# Is using a key shortcut for restart (Cmd + Ctrl + Power) bad in any way?

Tags: macos, shortcut, restart

I restart my Mac (for various reasons) often, about once a day. Recently I found about the key shortcut to do this: `Cmd` + `Ctrl` + `Power`. I really like this because it's fast and avoids that annoying prompt about "reopening windows when coming back".

My question: is using key shortcut `Cmd` + `Ctrl` + `Power` forceful, aggressive or potentially damaging in any way (like losing recent data)? Or, it is the same thing as doing it by clicking the menu options ( -> Restart... -> Restart).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Power button</kbd> will force a restart without any intervention from the system. Applications will not be closed in a proper way and everything that is not yet written to disk will be lost.

**It is definitely not safe.**

You could use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Power button</kbd> to shutdown and then <kbd>Power button</kbd> to start.

> Quit all apps (after giving you a chance to save changes to open documents), then shut down the computer

Comment: interestingly, http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 gives 2 versions of Command Control Power - one safe, the other not. I'm guessing typo.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not really the other one also have option in the combination

Comment: Confused me - it specifically says both… Command-Control-power button Force the Mac to restart

Command-Control-Power button
Quit all apps (after giving you a chance to save changes to open documents), then restart the computer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to Restart **without** the dialog, by key-command…
an alternative, which is not truly intuitive, is to set up a key combo from
System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

For example, you add Restart… as a combo
…which irritatingly then puts another Restart into the  menu (it also does the same for Shutdown.)

So, the fix is then to add a second shortcut for Restart itself - which must be different to the first one, of course.

Giving you something like this
 <sub>the 'Force Quit System Prefs' in the  menu is generated by the key command to take the picture</sub>

[image]

Comment: A combo for a safe restart already exists: Command-Option-Control-Power button (Quit all apps (after giving you a chance to save changes to open documents), then shut down the computer)

Comment: That's shutdown, not restart, though. I don't have a power button on my keyboard, so I've always had my own combos set up anyway.